# A conditional statement that I can't understand

Tags: c++, string, conditional-statements

I saw a few lines of code in a C++ tutorial video

```
void copy_string(char* from, char* to)
{
    while ((*to = *from) != '\0')
    {
        to++;
        from++;
    }
}
```

The function is used to copy the string "from" into the string "to", but I can't understand the conditional statement inside the while loop. Why is it able to assign and compare at the same time?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_assignment: "returns an lvalue identifying the left operand after modification. ".

Comment: This question should be tagged C; it has nothing to do with C++. The assignment operator (`=`) returns the assigned value, which can then be used in an expression just like any other value. Also, one could write `while (*to++ = *from++);` to achieve (almost) the same thing, but that would do two extra useless increments at the end (which the compiler may or may not optimize away, depending on the circumstances). Last but not least, this approach can be dangerous: If the buffer pointed at by `to` is shorter than the distance to `'\0'` in `from`, then all hell breaks loose.

Comment: "Why is it able to assign and compare at the same time?" ...Because there is an assignment operator (`=`) and a comparison operator (`!=`) written there? Why shouldn't it be able to?

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek: If OP is using a C++ compiler for compiling the code, then, according to the tag description, it is correct to tag it C++ instead of C, even if the code is "C style".

Comment: Some implementations of the above are simply: `while (*to++ = *from++) {}`

Comment: @selbie even simpler: `while (*to++ = *from++);`

Answer (score 2):

It's both an assignment `*to = *from` as well as a comparison

```
(*to = *from) != 0
```

It first assigns the dereferenced pointer from "from" to "to" then checks if the assigned value was equal to 0 which is a null terminator. If so, then exit the loop and the copying is done.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it able to assign and compare at the same time?

The same expression both assigns and compares because it contains a separate operator for each purpose.

`=` is an assignment operator.  It assigns the value of the right-hand operand to the left-hand operand (this is technically  a side effect) and it evaluates to the value that was assigned.  That it evaluates to a value may be the point you are missing.

`!=` is a comparison operator.  It determines whether the values of its left-hand and right-hand operands are unequal.  If so, it evaluates to 1, otherwise, it evaluates to 0.

There is also `==`, a comparison operator that evaluates whether the values of its left-hand and right-hand operands are equal (opposite of `!=`) without modifying the value of either one.

Do note, however, that although the overall expression performs both assignment and comparison, those don't necessarily happen *at the same time*.